# Have there been any ICO (Initial Coin Offerings) that has been backed by redemption of a physical product?

Tags: ico-initial-coin-offering

I'm doing some research on ICO's and wanted to see if there has been any ICO's that is backed by a physical product provided by a company? Aside from just funding the coin's development, the coin can function as an in store credit system? Which company or coins had this implemented?

Comment: I don't think "posting on stackexchange" quite counts as "doing some research". (at least, not serious research)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know at least two such ICO's [EcoBit](http://ecobit.io), which claims to be the **"WORLD'S FIRST-EVER GREEN BLOCKCHAIN PROJECT"**.

One thing that I like about the project is they have actually started physical work and have posted videos of their progress on their Facebook page (do check them out).

Another one that I know so far is [mona.co](http://mona.co),

> Introducing Monaco - world's best cryptocurrency card. Spend and send
>   money globally at perfect interbank exchange rates, saving EUR30-40 on
>   every EUR500 equivalent spent.